# Capacitor Numbers, What do these markings mean?

Tags: capacitor, markings

I have this capacitors and I tried learning how to read them but I am still unsure. I believe these are 330uf 16v capacitors but I dont know what the 282 means. Or if I am even correct.

What do these markings mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree its a 330uF 16V capacitor.
The 282 appears to be a production or lot code.

The information is found in datasheets, so you would need to determine the manufacturer and series to be sure.

Just as an example. Here is a snippet I took out of a datasheet for a capacitor with similar markings. The brand in this example is Cornell Dubilier.
[image: datasheet snippet]